# How to allow PC access to Android device files?

Tags: android, usb

I'm currently programming an Android app that will be the primary application on an Android device. This app is designed for business use on a custom Android device, so the user of the Android device cannot exit the application, or access any settings. (Status bar is disabled as well) They only have access to this app.

That being said, my Android application will write files to memory on the Android device. These files need to be able to be transferred from the Android device to a connected PC. (Connected via a USB cable)

I'm currently in the process of investigating how to get these files off of the Android system and could use some suggestions. I'd prefer that when the user connects the PC to the Android device via USB, a popup would appear that would give the connected PC access to the files on the Android device. (Similar to what happens when you change USB preferences to File Transfer and get access to files through File Explorer)

I've done some investigation so far, and most of what I've come up with involves sending a file over a network connection or creating an application on the Windows side that uses a Socket between the Android and PC. For the scope of this project, I will not be able to create a PC application and need a way to send the files externally using my application.

What are some methods to accomplish this? Is there a way to prompt the user to enable File Transfer for the connected device?

Comment: You are attempting to use USB in the inverse of the normal approach. Normally, the PC is the USB host accessing stuff supplied by the Android device (acting as a USB peripheral). In that mode, the peripheral does not have arbitrary access to stuff on the host. If you're willing to skip USB, you could look into jCIFS or similar client libraries for accessing Windows network shares, and have the Android app go that route.

Comment: I might be interpreting your response wrong, but I want the PC to act as the host in this case right? I don't want the Android app to manually send a file over to the PC. I just want the Android app to be able to enable or request whatever setting is necessary for the PC to get file access. (And therefore be able to find the files via the PC's File Explorer)

Comment: I interpreted "need a way to send the files externally using my application" as you wanting the Android app to push files to the PC, not have the user of the PC browse using File Explorer. My apologies if I misinterpreted that part of your question. "I just want the Android app to be able to enable or request whatever setting is necessary for the PC to get file access" -- unless there is an action for that in `android.provider.Settings`, I don't think apps have a way to do that. But, if this is a custom Android device, perhaps lock file transfer mode as being on in the firmware.

Comment: No worries. I'll check the android.provider.Settings here, but I don't recall seeing one. And sadly, though this is a custom device, I do not believe that it will be rooted so I don't know if I can make sure that setting is always enabled. (At least for the first release of this application)

Comment: With respect to the firmware change, in theory that's something the device vendor or reseller should be able to do for you. Whether they offer that option, though, is a whole 'nuther matter.

Comment: Sadly, I probably won't be able to get custom firmware for what I want quite yet. I was hoping to get something working here without that, but I might have to look into a different method. Thanks for your input though.